# Is there a current in \$R_1\$ in this precision rectifier if so, where does it go?

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, current, precision-rectifier

[image]

So Wikipedia on [Precision Rectifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_rectifier) says that :

> ... when the input is greater than zero, \$D1\$ is off, and \$D2\$ is on, so the output is zero because the other end of \${\displaystyle R_{2}}\$ is connected to the virtual ground and there is no current through \${\displaystyle R_{2}}\$

Now when we see \$R_1\$ it has a potential drop of \$V_{in}\$ across its ends , so a current must flow through it. But then where does it go? I cannot see a closed loop in which current can flow. It can only go through \$D1\$ but then it cannot flow back into op amp.

So my question is : In which path does the current flow? or If there is no current flowing through \$R_1\$ how is there a potential difference across it?

Comment: No current can go into inputs of an ideal op amp but op amp can sink current.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *But then where does it go? I cannot see a closed loop in which current
> can flow. It can only go through D1 but then it cannot flow back into
> op amp.*

Sure it can (but not through D1). The op-amp output will be about 0.7 volts negative (in order to preserve the virtual ground at -Vin) and positive current will flow through R1, then through D2 and to the op-amp output: -

[image]